# Target class [EmailController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

i am trying to use smtp email in laravel. when i submit my register form i am getting this error
so far i have done all my configs. it is difficult to find what is the error so far i have used controller and mail class still cant resolve it

help

please help

this is my EmailController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Mail\SendigEmail;

class EmailController extends Controller
{
    function index()
    {
        return view('send_email');
    }

    function send(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',

        ]);

        $data = array(
            'name' => $request->name,
        );

        Mail::to('Receiver Email Address')->send(new SendigEmail($data));
        return back()->with('success', 'Thanks for contacting us!');
    }
}
```

---

this is my register form
register.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<section id="hero" class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ url('sendemail/send') }}">
                            @csrf


                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                    @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="Profession / Occupation" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Profession / Occupation') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="Profession/Occupation" type="text" class="form-control @error('Profession/Occupation') is-invalid @enderror" name="Profession / Occupation" value="{{ old('Profession / Occupation') }}" required autocomplete="Profession / Occupation">

                                    @error('Profession/Occupation')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                                    @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="PhoneNumber" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('PhoneNumber') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="PhoneNumber" type="number" class="form-control @error('phonenumber') is-invalid @enderror" name="PhoneNumber" value="{{ old('PhoneNumber') }}" required autocomplete="PhoneNumber">

                                    @error('PhoneNumber')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="State" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="inputState" class="form-label">State</label>
                                    <select id="inputState" class="form-select">
                                        <option selected>Choose..</option>
                                        <option>Nigeria</option>
                                    </select>

                                    @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Date of Birth') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="datepicker" width="250" />
                                    <script>
                                        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                                            uiLibrary: 'bootstrap'
                                        });
                                    </script>

                                    <script>
                                        $(document).ready(function() {
                                            var date_input = $('input[name="date"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
                                            var container = $('.bootstrap-iso form').length > 0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
                                            var options = {
                                                format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
                                                container: container,
                                                todayHighlight: true,
                                                autoclose: true,
                                            };
                                            date_input.datepicker(options);
                                        })
                                    </script>

                                    @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                    <button type="submit" name="send" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        {{ __('Register') }}
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

this my Mail class
SendMail.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class SendigEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public $emails;

    public function __construct($emails)
    {
        $this->emails = $emails;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.s
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('Message from Visitor')
            ->view('email_template')
            ->with('emails', $this->emails);
    }
}
```

.config mail file

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Mailer
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default mailer that is used to send any email
    | messages sent by your application. Alternative mailers may be setup
    | and used as needed; however, this mailer will be used by default.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mailer Configurations
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure all of the mailers used by your application plus
    | their respective settings. Several examples have been configured for
    | you and you are free to add your own as your application requires.
    |
    | Laravel supports a variety of mail "transport" drivers to be used while
    | sending an e-mail. You will specify which one you are using for your
    | mailers below. You are free to add additional mailers as required.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "ses",
    |            "postmark", "log", "array"
    |
    */

    'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.googleemail.com.io'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),
            'username' => env('hamjeth68@gmail.com'),
            'password' => env('0752283810Hamjeth'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
        ],

        'ses' => [
            'transport' => 'ses',
        ],

        'mailgun' => [
            'transport' => 'mailgun',
        ],

        'postmark' => [
            'transport' => 'postmark',
        ],

        'sendmail' => [
            'transport' => 'sendmail',
            'path' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'transport' => 'log',
            'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
        ],

        'array' => [
            'transport' => 'array',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'hamjeth'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Markdown Mail Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
    | theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
    | of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
    |
    */

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

my Route file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');


//Route::get('/', 'PageController@index')->name('root-page');
//Route::get('/page/{slug}', 'PageController@index')->name('page');

Route::get('/home-two', function () {
    return view('home2');
});

Route::get('/why1', function () {
    return view('why');
});

Route::get('/web', function () {
    return view('webinars');
});

Route::get('/contact1', function () {
    return view('contact');
});

Route::get('/lawma1', function () {
    return view('lawma');
});


Route::get('/news1', function () {
    return view('news');
});

Route::get('/commitment1', function () {
    return view('commitment');
});

Route::get('/support1', function () {
    return view('support');
});

Route::get('/business1', function () {
    return view('business');
});

Route::get('/partnership1', function () {
    return view('partnership');
});

Route::get('/Research1', function () {
    return view('Research');
});

Route::get('/donate1', function () {
    return view('donate');
});

Route::get('/Volunteer1', function () {
    return view('Volunteer');
});

Route::get('/payhere1', function () {
    return view('payhere');
});

Route::get('/book-now', function () {
    return view('booknow');
});

Route::get('/new-user', function () {
    return view('newuser');
});

Route::get('/', 'EmailController@index');
Route::post('/sendemail/send', 'EmailController@send');

Route::get('/personal-development', function () {
    return view('personaldevelopment');
});

Route::get('/inspiring-student', function () {
    return view('inspiringstudent');
});

//dd(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::all());
```

Comment: Which Laravel version are you using?

Comment: i am using laravel 8

Comment: IDEs like PhpStorm will automatically hint that your controller class is not properly imported, why & where.

Answer (score 3):

Recent Laravel versions [do not automatically apply namespace prefixes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/releases#routing-namespace-updates).

You should either reference your controller by using a `use` statement, or use the FQCN.

```php
// Option one, through a use statement.
use App\Http\Controllers\EmailController;

Route::get('/', [EmailController::class, 'index']);

// Option two, through FQCN.
Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\EmailController@index');
```

Comment: "Route::get('/', [EmailController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/sendemail/send', [EmailController::class, 'send']);"  as you said i edited the route and now its giving this error        " The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD"

Comment: You have defined a route for both the `get` and `post` method. Did you edit both of them?

Comment: can you explain me which route should be GET and which should be POST

Comment: The route with `'/sendemail/send'` should probably be `post`.

Comment: Route::get('/', [EmailController::class, 'index']);
Route::post('/sendemail/send', [EmailController::class, 'send']); Currently it is like this still i am getting the error